# Nested objects not being processed by `SerializerModifier` when class has custom Serializer (Jackson)

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

Okay, so I've built a functional custom `BeanSerializer`, which limits the depth of serialization, and I can use it as shown by creating a `SerializerModifier` and adding it to module.  This WORKS great and is called each time another nested field is encountered, creating the instance of `DepthLimitedSerializer` perfectly.  HOWEVER, when I add a custom serializer to the nested class (using `@JsonSerialize`), then my `modifySerializer` method NEVER RUNS on the nested field!

Here is the simple class hierarchy, of which we will serialize the outer instance of `Bar`:

```java
@Getter @Setter
public class BaseClass {
    private String id;
    private String someBaseProperty;
}
```

```java
@Getter @Setter
//@JsonSerialize(using = FooSerializer.class)
public class Foo extends BaseClass {
    private String someFooProperty;

}
```

```java
@Getter @Setter
public class Bar extends BaseClass {
    String someBarProperty;
    Foo fooOfBar;
}
```

And here is the simplified custom serializer to which you pass a `maxDepth` and if it reaches that depth, it ONLY serializes a single (`id`) field, otherwise, it simply calls the `super`:

```java
public class DepthLimitedSerializer extends BeanSerializer {
    public static int DEFAULT_DEPTH = 2;
    private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> maxDepth = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> DEFAULT_DEPTH);
    private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> currentDepth = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> -1);

    public DepthLimitedSerializer(BeanSerializerBase src, int depth) {
        super(src);
        maxDepth.set(depth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void serializeFields(Object bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (maxDepth.get() < 0 || currentDepth.get() < maxDepth.get()) {
            currentDepth.set(currentDepth.get() + 1);

            super.serializeFields(bean, gen, provider);

            currentDepth.set(currentDepth.get() - 1);
        } else {
            try {
                Arrays.stream(_props).
                    filter(p -> p.getName().equals("id"))
                    .findFirst().orElseThrow()
                    .serializeAsField(bean, gen, provider);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this simple test we populate a `Foo` and a `Bar` and serialize them:

```java
class SerializeTest {
    @Test
    void testSerialization() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setId("fooID");
        foo.setSomeBaseProperty("someBaseValue");
        foo.setSomeFooProperty("foo property value");

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setId("barId");
        bar.setSomeBaseProperty("base of Bar");
        bar.setFooOfBar(foo);
        bar.setSomeBarProperty("bar property value");

        String depthOfZero = testSerializationToDepthOf(bar, 0);
        System.out.println("depth of ZERO: " + depthOfZero);
        String depthOfOne = testSerializationToDepthOf(bar, 1);
        System.out.println("depth of ONE: " + depthOfOne);
    }

    String testSerializationToDepthOf(BaseClass model, int depth) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();
        jackson.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("TestModule");
        module.setSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                      JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                if (BaseClass.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getType().getRawClass())) {
                    return new DepthLimitedSerializer((BeanSerializerBase) serializer, depth);
                }
                return super.modifySerializer(config, beanDesc, serializer);
            }
        });

        jackson.registerModule(module);
        return jackson.writeValueAsString(model);
    }
}
```

This gives us exactly what we expect, notice that with a `depth` of `0`, we only get the `id` field of the nested `Foo fooOfBar`, which is correct, but at a `depth` of `1`, we get the full output.  This works to arbitrary depths just fine, and when it runs, that `modifySerializer` method as well as those in the `DepthLimitedSerializer` all run for EACH nested model!

```
depth of ZERO: {
  "id" : "barId",
  "someBaseProperty" : "base of Bar",
  "someBarProperty" : "bar property value",
  "fooOfBar" : {
    "id" : "fooID"
  }
}
depth of ONE: {
  "id" : "barId",
  "someBaseProperty" : "base of Bar",
  "someBarProperty" : "bar property value",
  "fooOfBar" : {
    "id" : "fooID",
    "someBaseProperty" : "someBaseValue",
    "someFooProperty" : "foo property value"
  }
}
```

HOWEVER!  If one of these subclasses of `BaseClass` requires custom serialization, and I attempt to add a custom serializer for a particular class, like `Foo`:

```java
public class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo> {

    public FooSerializer() {
        super(Foo.class);
    }

    public void serialize(Foo foo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("custom", foo.getId() + "!" + foo.getSomeFooProperty());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

And I uncomment the above `@JsonSerialize(using = FooSerializer.class)` line and assign the custom serializer to the class, then my `modifySerializer` method and all others are NEVER RUN for my custom-annotated nested class, and so the `depth` is ignored and the custom serializer just ALWAYS runs:

```
depth of ZERO: {
  "id" : "barId",
  "someBaseProperty" : "base of Bar",
  "someBarProperty" : "bar property value",
  "fooOfBar" : {
    "custom" : "fooID!foo property value"
  }
}
depth of ONE: {
  "id" : "barId",
  "someBaseProperty" : "base of Bar",
  "someBarProperty" : "bar property value",
  "fooOfBar" : {
    "custom" : "fooID!foo property value"
  }
}
```

The behavior I would have expected is for the `modifySerializer` method to STILL be run, and then for the `super.modifySerializer()` call to find that the `FooSerializer`, but instead it's only run for the top-level object (and others, not so custom annotated).

How can I achieve this behavior?  I tried to make the custom serializer `extends` DepthLimitedSerializer`, but they are of different types of Jackson` Serializer` and I have thus far been unable to reconcile them and get them to work together in the correct order!  Clearly I can't use the annotation to assign the serializer, but how can I?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final working solution.  I almost think it's a bug that serializers which were assigned via annotation are NOT processed by `SerializerModifiers` attached to the `ObjectMapper`.  Nothing in the documentation says they'll "modify serializers, but oh, not those serializers."  My solution is a bit hacky, but it works.

First, a custom `BeanSerializerFactory` to add running the modifiers if the serializer is found via annotation.  This happens right at the beginning of the overridden method anyway.

```java
public class FixedBeanSerializerFactory extends BeanSerializerFactory {
    public FixedBeanSerializerFactory(SerializerFactoryConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Object> createSerializer(SerializerProvider prov, JavaType origType)
            throws JsonMappingException {

        // Very first thing, let's check if there is explicit serializer annotation:
        final SerializationConfig config = prov.getConfig();
        BeanDescription beanDesc = config.introspect(origType);
        JsonSerializer<?> ser = findSerializerFromAnnotation(prov, beanDesc.getClassInfo());
        if (ser != null) {
            if (_factoryConfig.hasSerializerModifiers()) {
                for (BeanSerializerModifier mod : _factoryConfig.serializerModifiers()) {
                    ser = mod.modifySerializer(config, beanDesc, ser);
                }
            }
            return (JsonSerializer<Object>) ser;
        }

        return super.createSerializer(prov, origType);
    }

    @Override
    public SerializerFactory withConfig(SerializerFactoryConfig config) {
        return new FixedBeanSerializerFactory(config);
    }
}
```

Now, this `DepthLimitedSerializer` is a LOT longer than it needs to be, mostly because I had to duplicate a lot of the code from `BeanSerailzier`.  Why, you ask?  Because the `serialize` method in `BeanSerializer` is final, so I can't override it.  Instead, I'm forced to override `BeanSerializerBase` and copy a bunch of code from it.

```java
public class DepthLimitedSerializer extends BeanSerializerBase {
    public static final int DEFAULT_DEPTH = 2;

    private static final ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> maxDepth = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> DEFAULT_DEPTH);
    private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> currentDepth = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> -1);

    public static JsonSerializer<Object> forSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> serializer,
                                                       BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                       int depth) {

        if (serializer instanceof BeanSerializerBase) {
            return new DepthLimitedSerializer((BeanSerializerBase) serializer, depth);

        } else {
            BeanSerializerBuilder builder = new BeanSerializerBuilder(beanDesc);
            JavaType type = jackson.constructType(serializer.handledType());
            BeanPropertyWriter[] properties = {};
            BeanPropertyWriter[] filteredProperties = {};
            maxDepth.set(depth);
            return new DepthLimitedSerializer(serializer, type, builder, properties, filteredProperties);
        }
    }

    protected JsonSerializer<Object> src;

    public DepthLimitedSerializer(BeanSerializerBase src, int depth) {
        super(src);
        this.src = src;
        maxDepth.set(depth);
    }

    protected DepthLimitedSerializer(DepthLimitedSerializer depthLimitedSerializer,
                                     BeanPropertyWriter[] properties, BeanPropertyWriter[] filteredProperties) {
        super(depthLimitedSerializer, properties, filteredProperties);
        this.src = depthLimitedSerializer;
    }

    protected DepthLimitedSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> src, JavaType type, BeanSerializerBuilder builder,
                                     BeanPropertyWriter[] properties, BeanPropertyWriter[] filteredProperties) {
        super(type, builder, properties, filteredProperties);
        this.src = src;
    }

    protected DepthLimitedSerializer(BeanSerializerBase src, ObjectIdWriter objectIdWriter, Object filterId) {
        super(src, objectIdWriter, filterId);
        this.src = src;
    }

    protected DepthLimitedSerializer(BeanSerializerBase src,
                                     BeanPropertyWriter[] properties, BeanPropertyWriter[] filteredProperties) {
        super(src, properties, filteredProperties);
        this.src = src;
    }

    @Override
    public BeanSerializerBase withObjectIdWriter(ObjectIdWriter objectIdWriter) {
        return new DepthLimitedSerializer(this, objectIdWriter, _propertyFilterId);
    }

    @Override
    protected BeanSerializerBase withByNameInclusion(Set<String> toIgnore, Set<String> toInclude) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override // @since 2.11.1
    protected BeanSerializerBase withProperties(BeanPropertyWriter[] properties,
                                                BeanPropertyWriter[] filteredProperties) {
        return new DepthLimitedSerializer(this, properties, filteredProperties);
    }

    @Override
    protected void serializeFields(Object bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (maxDepth.get() < 0 || currentDepth.get() < maxDepth.get()) {
            currentDepth.set(currentDepth.get() + 1);

            super.serializeFields(bean, gen, provider);

            currentDepth.set(currentDepth.get() - 1);
        } else {
            try {
                JsonDepthLimited depthAnnotation = bean.getClass().getAnnotation(JsonDepthLimited.class);
                String defaultFieldName = depthAnnotation.defaultField();
                boolean includeNulls = depthAnnotation.includeNulls();
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(defaultFieldName)) {
                    if (!includeNulls) {
                        Arrays.stream(_props).
                                filter(p -> p.getName().equals(defaultFieldName))
                                .findFirst().orElseThrow()
                                .serializeAsField(bean, gen, provider);
                    } else {
                        Arrays.stream(_props).forEach(p -> {
                            try {
                                if (p.getName().equals(defaultFieldName)) {
                                    p.serializeAsField(bean, gen, provider);
                                } else {
                                    gen.writeNullField(p.getName());
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected BeanSerializerBase asArraySerializer() {
        if ((_objectIdWriter == null)
                && (_anyGetterWriter == null)
                && (_propertyFilterId == null)
        ) {
            return new BeanAsArraySerializer(this);
        }
        // already is one, so:
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public BeanSerializerBase withFilterId(Object filterId) {
        return new DepthLimitedSerializer(this, _objectIdWriter, filterId);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException {

        if (src == null || src instanceof BeanSerializerBase) {
            if (_objectIdWriter != null) {
                gen.setCurrentValue(bean); // [databind#631]
                _serializeWithObjectId(bean, gen, provider, true);
                return;
            }
            gen.writeStartObject(bean);
            if (_propertyFilterId != null) {
                serializeFieldsFiltered(bean, gen, provider);
            } else {
                serializeFields(bean, gen, provider);
            }
            gen.writeEndObject();

        } else {
            if (maxDepth.get() < 0 || currentDepth.get() < maxDepth.get()) {
                Class<?> t = src.handledType();
                src.serialize(t.cast(bean), gen, provider);
            } else {
                gen.writeNull();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "DepthAwareSerializer for " + handledType().getName();
    }
}
```

This annotation marks the classes included and lets us pass a few arguments.

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface JsonDepthLimited {
    String defaultField() default StringUtils.EMPTY;
    boolean includeNulls() default false;
}
```

And here is our POJO hierarchy to demonstrate:

```java
@JsonDepthLimited(defaultField = "id")
@Getter @Setter
public class BaseClass {
    private String id;
    private String someBaseProperty;
}
```

```java
@Getter @Setter
@JsonSerialize(using = FooSerializer.class)
public class Foo extends BaseClass {
    private String someFooProperty;
}
```

```java
@Getter @Setter
public class Bar extends BaseClass {
    String someBarProperty;
    Foo fooOfBar;
}
```

A custom serializer for `Foo`:

```java
public class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo> {
    protected FooSerializer() {
        super(Foo.class);
    }

    public void serialize(Foo foo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("custom", foo.getId() + "!" + foo.getSomeFooProperty());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

And finally, the demonstration:

```java
class SerializeTest {
    @Test
    void testSerialization() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setId("fooID");
        foo.setSomeBaseProperty("someBaseValue");
        foo.setSomeFooProperty("foo property value");

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setId("barId");
        bar.setSomeBaseProperty("base of Bar");
        bar.setFooOfBar(foo);
        bar.setSomeBarProperty("bar property value");

        String depthOfZero = testSerializationToDepthOf(bar, 0);
        System.out.println("depth of ZERO: " + depthOfZero);
        String depthOfOne = testSerializationToDepthOf(bar, 1);
        System.out.println("depth of ONE: " + depthOfOne);
    }

    String testSerializationToDepthOf(BaseClass model, int depth) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();
        jackson.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        SerializerFactoryConfig factoryConfig = new SerializerFactoryConfig();
        jackson.setSerializerFactory(new FixedBeanSerializerFactory(factoryConfig));

        if (depth >= 0) {
            SimpleModule fragmentModule = new SimpleModule("FragmentModule");
            BeanSerializerModifier modifier = new BeanSerializerModifier() {
                @Override
                public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                          JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                    if (beanDesc.getClassAnnotations().has(JsonDepthLimited.class)) {

                        return DepthLimitedSerializer
                                .forSerializer((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer, beanDesc, depth);
                    }
                    return serializer;
                }
            };

            fragmentModule.setSerializerModifier(modifier);
            jackson.registerModule(fragmentModule);
        }

        return jackson.writeValueAsString(model);
    }
}
```

And here in the final output you can see that the custom serializer runs when the `depth` is set to `1`, but doesn't run (null is used) when the depth is set to `0`, exactly as it should.

```
depth of ZERO: {
  "id" : "barId",
  "someBaseProperty" : "base of Bar",
  "someBarProperty" : "bar property value",
  "fooOfBar" : null
}
depth of ONE: {
  "id" : "barId",
  "someBaseProperty" : "base of Bar",
  "someBarProperty" : "bar property value",
  "fooOfBar" : {
    "custom" : "fooID!foo property value"
  }
}
```